# Conditionally Replace a specific Character in a string

Tags: php, char

I am trying to remove the `@` sign from a block of text.  The problem is that in certain cases (when at the beginning of a line, the `@` sign needs to stay.

I have succeeded by using the RegEx pattern `.\@`, however on when the `@` sign does get removed  it also removes the character preceding it.

Goal: remove all `@` signs UNLESS the `@` sign is the first character in the line.

```
<?php

function cleanFile($text)
{
    $pattern = '/.\@/';
    $replacement = '%40';
    $val =  preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
    $text = $val;
    return $text;
};

$text  = ' Test: test@test.com'."\n";
$text .= '@Test: Leave the leading at sign alone'."\n";
$text .= '@Test: test@test.com'."\n";
$valResult = cleanFile($text);
echo $valResult;

?>
```

Output:

```
Test: tes%40test.com
@Test: Leave the leading at sign alone
@Test: tes%40test.com
```

Comment: ^[[:print:]]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]    does this work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* do this with regex using a negative lookbehind: `/(?<!^)@/m` (an `@` sign **not** preceded by the start of a line (or the start of the string if you skip out the `m` modifier)).

[**Regex 101 Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/vL6lY4)

In code:

```
<?php
    $string = "Test: test@test.com\n@Test: Leave the leading at sign alone\n@Test: test@test.com;";
    $string = preg_replace("/(?<!^)@/m", "%40", $string);
    var_dump($string);
?>
```

which outputs the following:

```
string(84) "Test: test%40test.com
@Test: Leave the leading at sign alone
@Test: test%40test.com;"
```

[**Codepad demo**](http://codepad.org/UlmZ6M1y)

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for regexp in such simple case.

```
function clean($source) {
    $prefix = '';
    $offset = 0;
    if( $source[0] == '@' ) {
         $prefix = '@';
         $offset = 1;
    }

    return $prefix . str_replace('@', '', substr( $source, $offset ));
}
```

and test case

```
$test = array( '@foo@bar', 'foo@bar' );
foreach( $test as $src ) {
    echo $src . ' => ' . clean($src) . "\n";
}
```

would give:

```
@foo@bar => @foobar
foo@bar => foobar
```

Comment: Your code will replace ALL `@` even if these are just after `\n`. Or you need to specify that string must be converted to array (which is nonesense)

Comment: Just remember to run this in a loop (`explode("\n", $text)` if you want it to work for all lines.

Comment: create and array from a string to use strpos? I think regexp will be a bit faster & will use less memory.

Comment: @arthem: nobody creates array here. You need to learn about ArrayAccess in PHP

Answer (score 0):

the syntax [^] means negative match (as in don't match), but I don't think the following would work

```
$pattern = '/[^]^@/';
```